# Linkedin Share Api using simple curl

Tags: api, curl, oauth, linkedin-api, unauthorized

I do a simple request to share something on my linkedin profile
I try to just do it with curl but it doesn't work

I set the content-type to JSON in the header and I also set the authorization in the header

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="V9uKPtEEB7JxQvYzbR2DuDfLe4qXjASgP5UhPJp8k13CYgSnN3BRFILxUJ6ApuCH",oauth_token="d6af5cda-b46e-4c38-b566-11428a9584fc",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="1PofnBExFc7pMB8b08fV34B5sTg%3D",oauth_timestamp="1323544645",oauth_nonce="516e0a1eadda4c24bfbcc4ca5e0cbedc",oauth_version="1.0"' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"recipients":{"values": [{"person":{"_path": "/people/~"}}]}, "subject": "JSON POST test", "body": "You rule"}' http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares
```

When I post this I get this result

```
About to connect() to api.linkedin.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 216.52.242.83... connected
* Connected to api.linkedin.com (216.52.242.83) port 80 (#0)
> POST /v1/people/ICshCGDT79/shares HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: api.linkedin.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="V9uKPtEEB7JxQvYzbR2DuDfLe4qXjASgP5UhPJp8k13CYgSnN3BRFILxUJ6ApuCH",oauth_token="d6af5cda-b46e-4c38-b566-11428a9584fc",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="1PofnBExFc7pMB8b08fV34B5sTg%3D",oauth_timestamp="1323544645",oauth_nonce="516e0a1eadda4c24bfbcc4ca5e0cbedc",oauth_version="1.0"
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 120
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 19:17:14 GMT
< Vary: *
< x-li-format: xml
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 393
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
  <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1323544635447</timestamp>
  <request-id>9UR4KT2T5Z</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:V9uKPtEEB7JxQvYzbR2DuDfLe4qXjASgP5UhPJp8k13CYgSnN3BRFILxUJ6ApuCH|d6af5cda-b46e-4c38-b566-11428a9584fc|*01|*01:1323544645:1PofnBExFc7pMB8b08fV34B5sTg=</message>
</error>
* Connection #0 to host api.linkedin.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Anyone can tell me where am I wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you thought of using the [Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api)?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've authorized against the API - thus the 401 Unauthorized error. You need to authorize a LinkedIn user, and then share as that user, not as the application itself. Check the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

Comment: I did actually, I didn't precise it in my post but I use the access token of a user connected to my linkedin application.

Comment: Hmm, why are you using the member ID to post the share instead of the ~? I've never tried it, but I don't see it mentioned in the docs that posting a share by specifying the ID is possible as shares are always meant to be generated by the current user, thus ~ should be used.

Comment: I tried both, and this is the same result

Comment: Have you tried running the XML you'd like to share through the [Rest Console](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/rest-console/)? If you can get that to work, then you can at least determine that it is an OAuth issue rather than a Share API issue.